# Answering a cli prompt in ruby with open3?

Tags: ruby, automation

Apologies for lack of sample code,  I'm on mobile at the moment.

I've gotten ruby+open3 to run commands and save stdout and stderr to a variable.

My question is,  if the command line interface prompts the user is it possible to input text into the prompt and press enter?   If so how would I go about doing this.

Example explanation 
Runs program,  program in terminal then asks "what is your name?"  and waits for input.

I want to input a name,  press enter.

Then it asks next question,  I want to put to stdin and answer that as well

This is for an automation test.   If anyone has a better idea than open3 I'm all ears but I'm restricted to ruby

Thanks

Comment: "Apologies for lack of sample code, I'm on mobile at the moment. " -> So you know you're doing something wrong but you're doing it anyway ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

Create an input file using:

```
cat > test.input
bar
baz
```

Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to terminate the input, which will cause the file `test.input` to be created.

In the same directory save this code as `test.rb`:

```
2.times do |i|
  user_input = gets.chomp
  puts "#{ i }: #{ user_input }"
end
```

Run the code using:

```
ruby test.rb < test.input
```

and you should see:

```
0: bar
1: baz
```

The reason this works is because `gets` reads the STDIN (by default) looking for a line-end, which in this case is the character trailing `bar` and `baz`. If I load the input file in IRB it's easy to see the content of the file:

```
input = File.read('test.input')
=> "bar\nbaz\n"
```

`2.times` says to read a line twice, so it reads both lines from the file and continues, falling out of the `times` loop.

This means you can create a file, pipe it into your script, and Ruby will do the right thing. If Ruby has called a sub-shell, the sub-shell will inherit Ruby's STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR streams. I can rewrite the test.rb code to:

```
puts `sh ./test.sh < #{ ARGV[0] }`
```

and create `test.sh`:

```
for i in 1 2
do
  read line
  echo $i $line
done
```

then call it using:

```
ruby test.rb test.input
```

and get:

```
1 bar
2 baz
```