# Simulating command prompt commands

Tags: ruby, command, popen3

"[Answering a cli prompt in ruby with open3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953821/answering-a-cli-prompt-in-ruby-with-open3)" is a possible duplicate question but it has no answer.

I need to write a program which compiles and executes a C program, gives inputs and returns the output. So far I came up with this:

For single input:

```
Open3.popen3('one.exe') do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  stdin.puts "45\n"
  STDOUT.puts stdout.gets
end
```

and the outputs is:

```
Enter the temperature in degrees fahrenheit: The converted temperature is 7.222222
```

For two or more inputs:

```
Open3.popen3('two.exe') do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  stdin.puts "45 45"
# This line works the same as the previous one.
# stdin.puts "45\r\n45"
  stdin.close

  STDOUT.puts stdout.gets
end
```

and the output is:

```
Enter first number: Enter second number: Sum is 90
```

The problem is, I did not get back the inputs I put in.

Is there a way I can correct it or maybe a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

Create an input file using:

```
cat > test.input
bar
baz
```

Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to terminate the input, which will cause the file `test.input` to be created.

In the same directory save this code as `test.rb`:

```
2.times do |i|
  user_input = gets.chomp
  puts "#{ i }: #{ user_input }"
end
```

Run the code using:

```
ruby test.rb < test.input
```

and you should see:

```
0: bar
1: baz
```

The reason this works is because `gets` reads the STDIN (by default) looking for a line-end, which in this case is the character trailing `bar` and `baz`. If I load the input file in IRB it's easy to see the content of the file:

```
input = File.read('test.input')
=> "bar\nbaz\n"
```

`2.times` says to read a line twice, so it reads both lines from the file and continues, falling out of the `times` loop.

This means you can create a file, pipe it into your script, and Ruby will do the right thing. I can rewrite the test.rb code to:

```
puts `sh ./test.sh < #{ ARGV[0] }`
```

and create `test.sh`:

```
for i in 1 2
do
  read line
  echo $i $line
done
```

then call it using:

```
ruby test.rb test.input
```

and get:

```
1 bar
2 baz
```

Since backticks are one of many ways to call a sub-shell or run code, you can adjust the calling code and/or the child, to read a file. Or have Ruby read the input and generate the file to be called. Or investigate using Expect, but I won't wish that on anyone.

That should help get you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried above examples and they work as expected, so i jump back to my original task, contents of **temp.rb** :`puts %x[sh ./test.sh < test.input]` content of **test.sh**: `./temp.o
read line
echo $line` and in test.input i just put 56 and the answer was still same it did not print the input. Output was: **Enter the temperature in degrees fahrenheit: The converted temperature is 13.333333**